# FCM trying to get a latitude and longitude of a person, wherever he/she get a notification to him/her in android

Tags: android

I am using FCM and getting a notification too, in that trying to get a latitude and longitude of a person, wherever he or she gets a notification to him or her without entering an application in android but getting 0.0 in latitude and longitude.

I am not done anything in MainActivity because get a location in the background and send that to a server

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService  {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private String msg;
    private String userEmail;
    private String getMessageId;
    private String getMessageType;
    private String Mmobile;
    private String msgTitle;
    private  Bitmap bitmap=null;
    private String url;
    private int sender_id;
    private NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle notiStyle;
    private NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    Double latitude, longtude;
    private LatLng latLng;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    float googleApiAccuaracy;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;



    /**
     * Called when message is received.
     *
     * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
     */
    // [START receive_message]
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());
               /* url=jsonObject.getString("image");
                Log.d("url ",url);*/
                msgTitle=jsonObject.getString("title");
                msg = jsonObject.getString("body");
                sender_id=jsonObject.getInt("senderId");


               /* if (url != null || url !=""){
                    bitmap = getBitmapfromUrl(url);

                }*/
                sendNotification(msg,bitmap,msgTitle);
                String FCM_ID = AppPreferences.getInstance(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this).getString(AppPreferences.FCM_REG_ID,
                        null);
                location();

              // CallLoginService(FCM_ID, String.valueOf(sender_id));
               /* DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);
                databaseAccess.open();
                String date=getDateTime();
                long status = databaseAccess.insertData(msgTitle,msg,url,date);
                Log.d("Status",status+"");
                databaseAccess.close();
                if (status != -1) {
                    UserNotification.notify(Constants.NOTIFICATION_REGRESH, "");
                } else {

                }*/

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }

    /*
     *To get a Bitmap image from the URL received
     * */
    public Bitmap getBitmapfromUrl(String imageUrl) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return bitmap;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        }
    }

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody, Bitmap image, String title) {

        notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String channelId = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationListActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 , intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
       // Bitmap tempBMP = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        //notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(tempBMP);
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(title);
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(messageBody);
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationBuilder.setSound(defaultSoundUri);

        if (image !=null){
            notiStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle();
            notiStyle.bigPicture(image);
            notificationBuilder.setStyle(notiStyle);
        }else {
            NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigText = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
            bigText.bigText(messageBody);
            notificationBuilder.setStyle(bigText);
        }
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            channel.setDescription(messageBody);
            channel.enableLights(true);
            channel.setLockscreenVisibility(111);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(sender_id  , notificationBuilder.build());

    }
    /**
     * CallLoginService
     */
    public void CallLoginService(String registrationId,String senderId) {

        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            headers.put("registrationId", registrationId);
            headers.put("senderId", senderId);

            //Make request to server
            new NotificationVollyPost().notificationVolleyPost(ServerUrls.NOTIFICATION_CHECKING,
                    new JSONObject(headers).toString(),
                            Constants.NOTIFICATION_PUSH_CHEK, this, null);

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String getDateTime() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
        String outputPattern = "dd-MMM-yyyy h:mm a";
        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(outputPattern);
        String str = null;
        str = outputFormat.format(date);
        Log.d("date",str);

        return str;
    }

    private  void location(){

        GPSTracker gp = new GPSTracker(this);
        if (Utilities.isGpsEnable(this, gp)) {
            if (latitude == null) {
                latitude = gp.getLatitude();
                longtude = gp.getLongitude();
                System.out.println("location"+latitude+" "+longtude);
            }
        } else gp.showSettingsAlert();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's very bad way to get location! You can not execute any code when notification is occurs and your app in background.

Comment: so can you please provide solution to do this

Comment: Use Foreground service or Job scheduler or any background service to keep your app live in background and do your location update work in it!

Comment: Beware! there will be also huge problems occurs in Android P & Q. Good luck!

Comment: Try `Fusedlocationproviderclient` instead of `GPSTracker`.